# Making a user login via a URL

Tags: php, url, authentication

Say you have a website A and some user B who is registered to use the site. If you send this user email updates whenever the site is updated, is there a way to make the user login to the site. Say for example, the link that you send him in the email, he needs to be logged in to view it, so is there any way that we can automatically log this user in when he visits the link, rather than him having to enter his username and password again. Obviously, sending the username and password in the URL is not safe, so was looking for other ideas. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a cookie on the users machine when they have logged in (if they tick a 'keep me logged in' or something).

That way, if you find the cookie when the user returns to your site, you'll know you can 'log them in'.

HOWEVER:

The cookie is per computer - which means that its not necessarily THE SAME PERSON who will arrive at your site from that machine.

You should probably only give enough privileges to greet the user by name, or whatever, but anything that accesses their private info or asks for payment etc should require them to re-enter their username and password.

Alternatively, just have the email direct the user to a page, which in turn redirects to login (but remembers in the session where they tried to go) and as soon as they login, take them to the correct destination page.  If they have asked their browser to store username/password on your site, this will be a trivial 2 second thing.

Don't underestimate how much users can like to feel that you're looking after their security, as well as the user-friendliness of your site.  The two things can be a trade off, and its important not to get the balance too far over to either end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how safe this is, but how about some kind of **hash**?

```
website.com?lh=2sdsdk...
```

and you find your user with it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MD5 ( concat ( id,'salt',email) )='$_GET[lh]'
```

You generate that hash with

```
$hash = md5($user->id.'salt'.$user->email);
```

But i have absolutely no idea how secure this idea is and it might take a lot of resources with *big* table of users, so any comments about this are more then welcome.

Comment: I thought about this as well but I was not sure about how secure this would be either.

Comment: I think md5 will be safe. Most websites use the above trick. you can add email/username to the url. find the particular record using this and then compare md5 hashes.

Comment: Its not terribly secure, OK - you're not giving away the username and password directly, so someone can't read the email over my shoulder and go off to their PC and log in to my account on your website.  If however, they gain access to my email (say I nip out of the office for two minutes, they can jot down the link, forward the email to themselves, or just plain hack into my webmail or something) they can easily gain access to my account on your website at which point they can CHANGE my password to something else, so I can no longer log in as me, and they can - and thus, my account is stolen.

Comment: I agree, but that's the problem of the idea itself. Only other way is for user (unless logged in) to input password.